# How to build sort direction in menu like Files app?

Tags: swiftui

I'm displaying sort options in my `Menu`, but I'd also like the user to control the sort direction in the way the Files app works: tapping a second time toggles the sort direction.

[image]

Here's what I have:

```
@State private var selectedSort: SortOption = .name
@State private var isSortAscending = true

enum SortOption {
    case name
    case number
    case length
}

Menu {
    Picker(selection: $selectedSort, label: Text("Sorting options")) {
        Button {
            isSortAscending.toggle()
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Name")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: isSortAscending ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.up")
            }
        }
        .tag(SortOption.name)
        Button {
            isSortAscending.toggle()
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Number")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: isSortAscending ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.up")
            }
        }
        .tag(SortOption.number)
        Button {
            isSortAscending.toggle()
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Length")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: isSortAscending ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.up")
            }
        }
        .tag(SortOption.length)
    }
}
```

Tapping doesn't toggle the sort state at all. Is there a better or more supported way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item selected is handled internally, so we need selection side-effect. It is possible to do by injecting `will-set` side effect in computable binding.

Here is a possible approach tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
var sorting: Binding<SortOption> { .init(
    get: { self.selectedSort },
    set: {
        if self.selectedSort == $0 {
            self.isSortAscending.toggle()
        }
        self.selectedSort = $0
    }
)}

var body: some View {
    Menu("Sort") {
        Picker(selection: sorting, label: Text("Sorting options")) {
            ForEach(SortOption.allCases) { option in
                HStack {
                    Text(option.rawValue)
                    Spacer()
                    if selectedSort == option {
                        Image(systemName: isSortAscending ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.up")
                    }
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestMenuSortOrderChange.swift)